# What limitations on customized memory management are there in win32?

Tags: windows, api, winapi, memory, assembly

So the addressable memory space in a 32-bit program is 4 gigabytes. Respectively, in a 64-bit application, there are ~18 exabytes of addressable space.

The kernel32.dll API has a variety of methods regarding the program's heap and/or memory.

So my current understanding is that for example if you call HeapAlloc and pass it the amount of memory you need to allocate, it will return a pointer to the address of that allocated memory space... (Please correct me if I'm wrong here though.)

Now the advantage of using the win32-api functions for this is obviously that Windows knows best where it put other components like loaded DLLs. That's why I'm asking...

Is there a fixed position in memory for DLL files. I think I read somewhere that for 32-bit it commonly is the upper half of the memory space (0x80000000 and up), but even if that's true, what would the position be for 64-bit applications?

Also, is it not possible to simply use pointers to some memory freely without having Windows allocate it first? What would the side-effects be?

I'm semi-new to this subject, so any help or hints are appreciated! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also, is it not possible to simply use pointers to some memory freely without having Windows allocate it first? What would the side-effects be?

The side effects are simple: your application would crash.

Windows (and every other sane OS) uses virtual memory: the OS maps physical memory into the virtual address space that your process sees. And it performs this mapping on demand: when you ask it to allocate a block of memory, it maps a corresponding range of virtual memory addresses to a valid chunk of memory.

Writing to an arbitrary address means you'll hit a memory page that has not been mapped by the OS to any backing memory. Then you'll get an access violation (or segmentation fault on *nix)

> Is there a fixed position in memory for DLL files

Nope. How could there be? If you had *one* DLL file, it could be done. What if your application loads two DLLs? What if it loads 40? 400? And each DLL has a different size, so if they were loaded into fixed locations, they might end up overlapping.

On top of this, recent versions of Windows perform address space randomization: to mitigate certain security exploits, Windows tries to ensure that it loads DLLs and executables to *different* locations if you launch the application multiple times.

In short: your process runs under Windows. It is a Windows citizen and has to obey Windows laws. If it needs to access a resource (including, but not limited to, memory), it has to ask Windows to please make that resource available.

Comment: I'm not sure that virtual memory has much to do with sanity... it's more a characteristic of general purpose OSes.  Implementing virtual memory on an 8-bit microcontroller would not be sane.